# regarding php curl and curl command

Tags: php, curl

Php curl returning blank page for some sites where curl command working fine.

for example : curl **www.wikipedia.org** generating output but php curl giving blank pages with `<html>` tags

```
$ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl with given url

//TBD: all setopt commands return true/false. Should be handled

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent

$res = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0); // stop when it encounters an error

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // iNetClean is web-crawling, no need to verify certificates

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ""); // accept all encodings - identity, deflate, gzip
// now set the URL

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$fp_out = fopen($html_file, 'w');
if (!$fp_out) {
    if ($DEBUG) {
        error_log("couldn't create " . $html_file);
    }
} else {
    if ($DEBUG) {
        error_log("file created " . $html_file);
    }
}

$fp_err = fopen($html_err_file, 'w');
if (!$fp_err) {
    if ($DEBUG) {
        error_log("couldn't create " . $html_err_file);
    }
} else {
    if ($DEBUG) {
        error_log("error file created " . $html_err_file);
    }
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp_out); //rawurlencode($url) . "txt"); // for debugging only
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp_err);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//0 size file is created if no data is downloaded or URL does not exist such as pron00.com. Hence added handler to such errors.
if (@filesize($html_file) > 0) {
    //file exists and contain some data
} else {
    return false;
}
if ($result == false) {
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    if ($DEBUG) {
        error_log("Curl_exec fail");
    }
    return false;
}

fclose($fp_out);
fclose($fp_err);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

Comment: have u assigned $url = "www.wikipedia.org";

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using below code:

```
<?php

$debug = 1;
$fb_page_url = "http://www.wikipedia.org";
$cookies = 'cookies.txt';
touch($cookies);
$uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36';


/**
    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init($fb_page_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];



/**
 Start Fetching process
 */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fb_page_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9850);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
//$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = ""; //this is for further clicking any link
//$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ""; //this is for further clicking any link
$postfields['__LASTFOCUS'] = "";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['hidStates'] = "";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result as fetched web page.

    if ($debug) {
        echo $ret;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: By giving eventtarget and eventargument you can also click any link if you want. I think this might helps you.

Comment: This is, in no way, answering the question... This just looks like a random copy-paste of some curl request to a specific page. I mean: why would `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9850);` even make a difference here? there is no timeout issue being reported by the op, so why set it so ridiculously high?